# Prevent two fixed components from overlapping

Tags: javascript, css

I have been struggling to make an element that I prepend to a page not overlap with the `fixed` component already existant on the page.

For example, you can execute the following in console on Stackoverflow :

```
const rootElement = document.createElement("div");
rootElement.id = "chrome-bar";


document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style["paddingTop"] = "40px";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style["position"] = "relative";

document.body.prepend(rootElement); rootElement.innerHTML="Hello World";rootElement.style="position:fixed;z-index:99999;top:0;background-color:black;width:100vw;color:white;"
```

As you can see, the black bar overrides the `header` tag, because of its `position : fixed` style. How could I have both of these bars (the one I create & the SO navbar) fixed and not overlap ? i.e. the behaviour that happens when you insert the same snippert on github (whose nav is not fixed)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Create a parent that is fixed instead

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for the reply ! In order to make applicable to all sites  I guess I could find all the fixed elements & create a parent fixed div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat of a crude workaround, but you could create a `div` with a fixed height and displace the existing `header` element by the same amount.

```js
const rootElement = document.createElement("div");
rootElement.id = "chrome-bar";

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style["paddingTop"] = "40px";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style["position"] = "relative";

document.body.prepend(rootElement);
rootElement.innerHTML = "Hello World";
let divHeight = "30px"
rootElement.style = `position:fixed;z-index:99999;top:0;background-color:black;width:100vw;height:${divHeight};color:white;`

let header = document.querySelector("body > header")
header.style.setProperty("top", divHeight, "important")
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the reply! The problem is that Im looking for a universal solution, not only appliable to SO, hence I cannot assume there will always be a `header` or a `nav` element

Comment: @PeterMalik I don't think it is feasible to come up with a general solution to this problem since we cannot know the structure and styles of an arbitrary website. If you have specific sites in mind, I would recommend working case by case.

Comment: I'm not so sure, because Ive seen some plugins that do work like that ...